# Android API 21 22 datepicker year selection bug?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-datepicker

I've implemented the "calendar view", i.e., lollipop version of Android's Datepicker.
There's a difference between Android API 21 & 22 in the year selection of said datepicker when I click on "2015" to change the year:

[using API21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSQgt.png)

[using API22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAaeq.png)

I'm using a Nexus 5 simulator. I'm only seeing the current (2015) year entry in API22, whereas in API21, I can scroll through from ~1950 to ~2100. Same code and, as far as I can tell, same simulation settings.

I'm wondering if this is just a bug, if anyone else has encountered it, or has any tips for a workaround? I really like the calendar view that Lollipop offers so preferable if I can get this working right. Will update with any new information I find.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly calling `setMaxDate` and `setMinDate`?

Comment: Thanks Eugen! That's what i tried eventually and it fixed. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a quick fix. Programmatically set the min and max dates of the DatePickerDialog object. I did so in the [DatePickerFragment static class definition](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePickerFragment), so every instance of DatePickerDialog gets set:

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), YourActivityHere, year, month, day);
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().getMinDate());
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().getMaxDate());
```

You can also set this if you defined DatePickerDialog in an XML activity, but I'm not sure if the bug exists there.

Comment: So setting the values that are already supposed to be there fixes it? Wicked :D

Comment: Use this link to file a bug report, otherwise they won't (also follow the instructions in the template): https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Developer%20bug%20report

Comment: 3 years later, same issue :)  and I'd like to see your answer marked as correct.

Comment: @theOranguzang I am not able to scroll beyond 2100 year any idea why Android does that ?